# Bootstrap and IE9/8 - making me crazy

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

What is the problem with Bootstrap in IE8/9?

http://www.stockholmcharterguide.com/

I've scanned the web and found some trix but - still the same grey overlay.

Is there a difference if you use the html5shiv.min.js local or remote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your question is, but from checking the link I see a tag written like so in the **top menu**:

```
<!--li>
    <a href="medelhavet" class="medelhavet" title="Hyr en yacht i Medelhavet">Medelhavet</a>
</li>
```

This: `<!--li>` effectively comments out your content from then on, all the way down to the bottom in your **footer** where you have this code:

```
<!--li><a href="/medelhavet" class="medelhavet" title="Hyr en yacht i Medelhavet">Medelhavet</a></li>
            <li><a href="/konferens" title="Sjönära konferensalternativ - garanterat lyckat resultat">Konferens</a></li-->
```

The result being nothing renders in between your top menu and footer, resulting in the empty gray box--it's not an overlay, it's the page background.

HTH,

-Ted